# Call established external tool from code

Tags: c#, vsix

I am currently creating a visual studio VSIX addin which creates an external tool in visual studio, and now I want to be able to call that stored external tool through the use of code, making reference to all the stored arguments in my external tools. Is there a nice way to explicitly reference the external tool?

eg. I've set up notepad++ as an external tool. Instead of calling C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++.exe, is there any way I can call process.start(external tool 6)?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "VSIX addin" is an oxymoron. Are you creating an add-in (which can't use VSIX deployment) or a VSIX package?

Answer (score 0):

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ExternalCommand6")
```

If you are using add-in you already have a DTE instance. If you are using a package, you can get a DTE instance: [visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages](http://visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages)

Comment: If you are using add-in you already have a DTE instance. If you are using a package, you can get a DTE instance: http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/